# .NET 8 WCF Invokes very slow using PeerTrust certificate validation

Tags: .net, wcf

After upgrading a legacy .NET 4.8 system to .NET 8, when the system calls a WCF service using `nettcp` binding, we found calls to a WCF service execute very slow when hosted on Linux.

The same .NET 8 code running on Windows can 'ping' the server in say 20ms, but in Linux whether on metal or in a container takes 150ms to 'ping' (Literally a method that just returns true). The call and security enforcement otherwise works.

We use self signed certificates to host the WCF Service.  which are in the `TrustedPeople` store.
The certs are mounted into the client container via `/root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores`

The server is configured like this in .NET 4.8

```
 <behavior name="netTcpBindingBehavior">
  <callbackDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <clientCredentials>
    <clientCertificate findValue="CN=local.oursystem.test" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
    <serviceCertificate>
      <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
    </serviceCertificate>
  </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, it was found that using `CertificateValidationMode=PeerTrust` runs very slow under Linux compared to Windows.

Implementing a custom validator sped it up

```
  /// <summary>
  /// PeerTrust mode is slow in Linux, so implement our own validator
  /// </summary>
  private class WcfServerX509CertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
  {
      string _expectedThumbprint;

      public WcfServerX509CertificateValidator(string expectedThumbprint)
      {
          Guard.NullOrEmpty(expectedThumbprint, "Certificate thumbprint required");
          _expectedThumbprint = expectedThumbprint;
      }

      public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
      {
          Guard.That(certificate.Thumbprint == _expectedThumbprint, () => $"Certificate was not issued by a trusted issuer. Received thumbprint={certificate.Thumbprint}, expected={_expectedThumbprint}");
      }
  }
```

The `ChannelFactory<T>` is configured with this snippet

```
 var serviceCertificate = factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate;
 serviceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
 var sslCertificateAuthentication = serviceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication;

 sslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;              // PeerTrust is slow under Linux
 sslCertificateAuthentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new WcfServerX509CertificateValidator(serverCertificate.Thumbprint);
```